# Can RavenDB persist documents to a filesystem?

Tags: file, persistence, ravendb, ram, persist

I need the following; I have a substantial collection of text files. I want them accessible (readonly) from ram for speed and persisted on disc (as the actual text file) for safety and access via Isilon. I was wondering if RavenDB is capable of doing this, or am I taking the 'document' to literaly?

Edit:
**OR** can the data *inside* the file (semi structured) be stored on disc, in a single file, not required to be in its original form, but still easily readable by other programs.

In other words, can RavenDB store a/every row in a file on disc?

Answer (score 1):

You don't need RavenDB for that.  Just use `System.IO.File` and related concepts.

Raven won't work with individual files on disk.  It keeps it's own set of files for its index and data stores.  Access from other programs is not allowed.  What happens in RavenDB, *stays* in RavenDB.

Most people store big files on disk, and then just store a file path or url reference to them in their RavenDB database.  Raven also supports the concept of [*attachments*](http://ravendb.net/docs/2.0/client-api/attachments), where the file is uploaded into Raven's database - but then it wouldn't be available as a single file on disk the way you are thinking.